# JSON output with Haskell

Tags: json, haskell

I am trying to use the show function and get back output that looks like JSON
The type I have to work with is

```
data JSON = JNum Double
          | JStr String
```

I am looking for

JNum 12, JStr"bye", JNum 9, JStr"hi"
to return

```
[12, "bye", 9, "hi"]
```

I have attempted:

```
instance Show JSON where
  show ans = "[" ++ ans ++ "]"
```

but fails with a compile error. 
I have also tried

```
instance Show JSON where
  show ans = "[" ++ ans ++ intercalate ", " ++ "]"
```

but failed with "Not in scope: data constructor 'JSON'
Not sure how to use "ans" to represent whatever type JSON receives as input in the ouput, be it a string, double..etc...
Not very good with Haskell so any hints would be great.

Thx for reading

Answer (score 2):

You can have GHC automatically derive a show function for you by adding `deriving (Show)` to your data declaration, e.g.:

```
data JSON = ... deriving (Show)
```

As for your code, in order for `show ans = "[" ++ ans ++ "]"` to type check `ans` needs to be a String, but `ans` has type JSON.

To write your own show function you have to write something like:

```
instance Show JSON where
   show (JNum d) = ... code for the JNum constructor ...
   show (JObj pairs) = ... code for the JObj constructor ...
   show (JArr arr) = ... code for the JArr constructor ...
   ...
```

Here `d` will have type Double, so for the first case you might write:

```
   show (JNum d) = "JNum " ++ show d
```

or however you want to represent a JSON number.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write your own instance, you can do something like this:

```
instance Show JSON where
  show (JNum x) = show x
  show (JStr x) = x
  show (JObj xs) = show xs
  show (JArr xs) = show xs
```

Note that for `JObj` and `JArr` data constructor, the show will use the instance defined for `JObj` and `JArr`.

Demo:

```
λ> JArr[JNum 12, JStr"bye", JNum 9, JStr"hi"] 
[12.0,bye,9.0,hi]
```

Comment: How come you wrote 
'show (JStr x) = x'
rather than 'show (JStr x ) = show x '?
Thank you

Comment: @SumYungGai They both are equivalent. `show x` will produce `String` but for `JStr s` data constructor, `s` is already a `String`

Comment: @Sibi Actually, they are not equivalent: if `s` is a string, `show s` will add quotes around `s`, as well as escape any quotes which might be inside `s`, and any other "special" characters.